# Unable to add a view to some projects using Smart Client Factory 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-3.5, scsf

I used to be able to add a view using the Smart Client Factory context menu in solution manager.

However now the only option available is "Create Disconnected Service Agent".

Having said that one of the projects has the "Add View" menu available.

Any ideas on how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem:

Microsoft.Practices.CompositeUI & Microsoft.Practices.CompositeUI.WinForms must be referenced by a project in order to add views to it.

(I was referencing custom CompositeUI and CompositeUI.WinForms projects instead)